# In typescript, can I have a class member that is an enum type, determined by the class constructor, which dictates other member types?

Tags: typescript, class, generics, enums, type-safety

## Backstory (You can skip)

I come from Qt/C++, and am still very new to typescript and javascript. The program philosophy I abide by in Qt/C++ can be summed up as, `Code everything as an API` and I am trying to learn how I can apply this in typescript. I am not particularly sure if this is something I need to use generics for, so I am going to go into detail. If this was C++, I would probably be using a template to do this.

Anyway, I want to create a class that serves as a basis for constructing internet polls.
Basically the idea is,

1. Create an object of a Poll Class `let question1 = new Poll(Fruit, "Fav Desert?");`
2. Constructor takes any enum type as an argument. `enum Fruit` or `enum Vegetable`
3. The enum type represents the options for a question. `Apple, Orange, Banana`
4. Enum type then dictates how the class will work.
5. So, if the enum type has 3 members, then 3 answers, one for each enum member, will be needed:

```js
// My stupid internet poll that determines what type of fruit you are
let question1 = new Poll(Fruit, "Favourite Dessert?");
question1.addOption("Banana Split", Fruit.Banana);
question1.addOption("Apple Pie"   , Fruit.Apple );
question1.addOption("Orange Cake" , Fruit.Orange);

let question2 = new Poll(Fruit, "Favourite Colour?");
question2.addOption("Yellow"      , Fruit.Banana);
question2.addOption("Red"         , Fruit.Apple );
question2.addOption("Orange"      , Fruit.Orange);
```

6. In a database, the popularity of each answer/enum member will be tracked, as well as how often the enum members are chosen overall.

So basically, I want my poll class to be built around an enum type, where internal checks are done to ensure things like type safety, number of options, no duplicates, etc...

## Actual Question

How do I make a class that takes an enumerator type as a constructor argument, and uses that enumerator type to set the type of class member variables?
Will this be typesafe?

In my mind, it looks something like this:

```js
class Poll
{
    constructor( T: enum ) // T for enum type
    {
        this.m_T = T; // Pseudo code. Setting enum type used internally
    }
    private type m_T      : enum    ;// Pseudo code, Enum Type
    private m_Options     : m_T   [];// Pseudo code, typesafe array of Enum Type
    private m_OptionsText : string[];// Corresponds with m_Options
    
    addOption(optionText: string, option: m_T ) : void 
    {
        this.m_Options    .push( option     ); 
        this.m_OptionsText.push( optionText );
    }
}

enum Fruit {
    Apple = 0,
    Orange,
    Banana,
}

enum Vegetable {
    Carrot = 0,
    Broccoli,
    Lettuce,
}

let question1 = new Poll(Fruit, "Favourite Dessert?");
// Typesafe
question1.addOption("Banana Split", Fruit.Banana     ); // Should work
// NOT Typesafe, because question1 was not consructed with Vegetable enum
question1.addOption("Carrot Cake" , Vegetable.Carrot ); // Should NOT work
```

Thanks.

Comment: Would generics like `class Poll<T>` work? Then call it with `new Poll<Fruit>('Favourite Dessert?')`

Comment: @K48 Yep; that works. Funny that such a detailed question is summed up as, "Just use a generic".